# Drag item from Datagridview control into a TreeView control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that has rows, but its not using a full row selection.  The way I select items in DataGridView is just by the Column's individual value for that particular row. E.g.  `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString`

I'm trying to find out how I can make it so when I click in the First ColumnValue in Row 1 and drag it to a TreeView Control, it will create the NODE for whatever Value was Dragged from Row 1 Column 1

Comment: For starters please post relevant code and where you are stuck and we will be glad to help. ***How can I make it*** , we are not here to program it for you, but rather help with a specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

After doing some more digging I was able to find what I was looking for.  I understand stack overflow isn't here to write a program for me, however stack overflow was built in the concept of "helping" with pushing people into the right direction and not "trolling"

Here's the code I found and modified to get it to work

Since my TreeView is built dynamically, I had to set an addhandler manually.  Normally if you have a TreeView already, you could just use Handles as shown with the datagridview drag

```
   AddHandler DirTree.DragEnter, AddressOf treeView1_DragEnter
    AddHandler DirTree.DragDrop, AddressOf treeView1_DragDrop


Private dragedItemText As String
    Private Sub treeView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
        Dim pt As Point
        Dim destinationNode As TreeNode
        pt = DirTree.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        destinationNode = DirTree.GetNodeAt(pt)
        Dim dragedNode As New TreeNode()
        dragedNode.Text = dragedItemText
        lblTitle.Text = dragedItemText

        destinationNode.Nodes.Add(dragedNode)
        dragedItemText = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub treeView1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End Sub

    Private Sub dataGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then

            dragedItemText = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString 
          'Cells(0) for first column
            DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dragedItemText, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        End If
    End Sub
```